# how to run a asp.net app not only under http://localhost:49809

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

is it possible to run a asp.net application via visual studio 2010 not always under `http://localhost:49809`?

the problem: I have a page which have some bugt with the paths, but under `/` it run well.
but I want to test it e.g. under a url like:

```
http://localhost:49809/mypage/foo/[and here the page as before]
```

Comment: Install IIS and Publish the site to be hosted there.

Comment: but then its not so easy to debug as running it via visual studio

Comment: Fair point. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your application -> properies (shortcut <kbd>F4</kbd>). There you can set the port number, and a virtual path if necessary:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Visual Studio to run the site. Install IIS and create a site there pointing to the disk location of your project. This way any change in your code will be reflected there as well, same way as before.

Now to debug it you will have to:

1. Run Visual Studio as admin
2. Click Debug --> Attach to Process
3. Choose w3wp.exe and confirm.

That's it, now you debug same way like you debugged before when hosting via the VS itself.

If you want you can also add such line to your code at any point you need to always debug:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```